Handling UART Rx responses
Looking to implement a user startup screen via a UART terminal. I'm trying to handling the response terminal. I can display the terminal splashcreen. How can I handle the UART receive to and display the response once the user has inputted their response and not on every loop.
enum splashscreen_response_type
{
  TEST_RESPONSE_VALID,
  TEST_RESPONSE_INVALID,
  TEST_RESPONSE_UNKNOWN,
  TEST_RESPONSE_MAX
};



int bootup_disp()
{
  uint8_t  test_type_response = TEST_RESPONSE_UNKNOWN;
  char input[100];              // Buffer to hold the user input
  uint8_t  processed_input;
  uint8_t  chosen_test;
  uint8_t  resp_buff[1];

   
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"USER CHOICE TYPE 1 for test:", sizeof("USER CHOICE TYPE 1 for test:"), 500);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"TYPE USER CHOICE:", sizeof("TYPE USER CHOICE:"), 500);

  do{
      HAL_UART_Receive(&hlpuart1,splash_resp_buff, 1,500);
      
      if(resp_buff == 1)
      {
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"CORRECT CHOICE", sizeof("CORRECT CHOICE")-1, 500);
          test_type_response = TEST_RESPONSE_VALID);
          
      }
      else
      {
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"INCORRECT CHOICE", sizeof("INCORRECT CHOICE")-1, 500);
      }
  }
  while (test_type_response != TEST_RESPONSE_VALID);*/

  HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)splash_resp_buff, sizeof(splash_resp_buff)-1, 500);

Modified as per comments

int bootup_disp()
{
  uint8_t  test_type_response = TEST_RESPONSE_UNKNOWN;
  char input[100];              // Buffer to hold the user input
  uint8_t  processed_input;
  uint8_t  chosen_test;
  uint8_t  resp_buff[1];


  HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"USER CHOICE TYPE 1 for test:", sizeof("USER CHOICE TYPE 1 for test:"), 500);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"TYPE USER CHOICE:", sizeof("TYPE USER CHOICE:"), 500);

  do{
      HAL_UART_Receive(&hlpuart1,resp_buff, 1,500);

      if(resp_buff[0] == '1')
      {
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"CORRECT CHOICE", sizeof("CORRECT CHOICE")-1, 500);
          test_type_response = TEST_RESPONSE_VALID;

      }

      else
      {
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"INCORRECT CHOICE", sizeof("INCORRECT CHOICE")-1, 500);
      }
  }
  while (test_type_response != TEST_RESPONSE_VALID);

  HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)resp_buff, sizeof(resp_buff)-1, 500);

}


HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1,(uint8_t*)"USER CHOICE TYPE 1 for test:", sizeof("Type User Choice:"), 500); this line (and the next one) are nonsense. More specifically, the arguments of sizeof() are nonsense. They are supposed to be the length of the string you're sending, not sizeof of a different string. It's one step away from undefined behavior the way it is. The first of those lines will send only half of the string that you want to send.

Also, you use variable that you haven't declared resp_buff. Your program will not compile, or you're omitting important parts of the program.

Additionally, please declare your memory buffers for UART as uint8_t or char, not int. The unit of data of UART is a char, while int can be 16 or 32 bits. You're asking for trouble mixing data types of different size without any need for that.

Hi
Made  the modifications to the code.

if(resp_buff == 1) should probably be if(resp_buff[0] == '1')

if(resp_buff == 1) this is false 100% of the time. resp_buff is an array = pointer, so it always contains something like 0x200000CD. You want if(resp_buff[0] == 1). Also, as correctly pointed out by pcmacfarlane, you need to distinguish ==1 and =='1'. 1 and '1' are different values. '1' is a printable character 1, its real binary value is 0x31.

ok I see. Made the above modification, placed it under modified as per comments

You still haven't fixed the if(resp_buff[0]...). You need to compare the first element of the array, not the memory address of the array.

sorry about that I made the change.

So what is the actual problem now? What happens and what did you expect to happen?

So thanks for the help it seems to work now. As stated by yourself and others it was the mismatch between character. I wanted to know if anyone had any suggestions on how I can an incorrect test message once the user has inputted an incorrect response and not every cycle. Currently, after every cycle it says incorrect response. Is there a way to display this message once the user inputs the incorrect command ?

HAL_UART_Transmit() will return HAL_OK if it received a character, and will return something else if it did not. So you could use that to know if anything was typed or not, and not print anything if nothing was typed. You should really be checking the return values from all HAL functions anyway.
